# How to avoid Multiple DMLs on a single transaction while populating Rollup fields in Lookup relationship using triggers

Tags: apex, trigger, dml

I have a trigger on child object.From the handler I am calling the helper method multiple times to update 4 rollup fields on parent record. I have a working logic but I am concerned about repeatedly calling the same method which is increasing DML calls. Below is the code

Handler :

```
public static void updateRollUpFields(List<Contact> conList) {
Set<Id> AccountSet = new Set<Id>();
for(Contact con : conList) {
    if(con.Client_Priority__c != NULL) {
        AccountSet.add(con.Client_Priority__c);
    }
}

ContactTriggerHelper.processSubCatRollUps(AccountSet,'subCat1');
ContactTriggerHelper.processSubCatRollUps(AccountSet,'subCat2');
ContactTriggerHelper.processSubCatRollUps(AccountSet,'subCat3');
ContactTriggerHelper.processSubCatRollUps(AccountSet,'subCat4');
}
```

Helper :

```
 public static void processSubCatRollUps(Set<Id> AccountSet, String subCategory) {
    List<Account> updateAccList = new List<Account>();
    List< Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Total_Sub1__c, Total_Sub4__c, Total_Sub2__c, Total_Sub3__c, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts WHERE Sub_LoS__c =: subCategory) 
                                         FROM  Account WHERE Id IN : AccountSet];
    for( Account accRecord : accList) {
        if(subCategory == 'subCat1') {
            accRecord.Total_Sub1__c = accRecord.Contacts.size();
        } 
        else if(subCategory == 'subCat2') {
            accRecord.Total_Consulting_LoS__c = accRecord.Contacts.size();
        }
        else if(subCategory == 'subCat3') {
            accRecord.Total_Sub2__c = accRecord.Contacts.size();
        }
        else if(subCategory == 'subCat4') {
            accRecord.Total_Sub3__c = accRecord.Contacts.size();
        }
        updateCpList.add(accRecord);
    }
    if(!updateCpList.isEmpty()) {
        UPDATE updateAccList;
    }
}
```

As shown above UPDATE is happening 4 times on a single transaction and I want to avoid it. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bulkify your code, meaning pass in all the subcategories at once. Here's an example implementation:

```
public static void processSubCatRollUps(
    Set<Id> accountIds, 
    Map<String, sObjectField> categoryFieldMapping
) {
    Map<Id, Account> accountsToUpdate = new Map<Id, Account>();
    for(Id accountId: accountIds) {
        Account tempAccount = new Account(Id=accountId);
        for(sObjectField field: categoryFieldMapping.values()) {
            tempAccount.put(field, 0); // Initialize to empty/zero
        }
        accountsToUpdate.put(accountId, tempAccount);
    }
    for(AggregateResult result: [SELECT AccountId AccountId, Sub_Los__c subLos, 
                                 COUNT(ID) totalContacts 
                                 FROM Contact 
                                 WHERE AccountId = :accountIds AND 
                                 Sub_LoS__c = :categoryFieldMapping.keySet() 
                                 GROUP BY AccountId, Sub_LoS__c]
    ) {
        accountsToUpdate.get((Id)result.get('AccountId')).put(
            categoryFieldMapping.get((String)result.get(subLos)), 
            (Integer)result.get('totalContacts')
        );
    }
    update accountsToUpdate.values();
}
```

Which is then called as:

```
ContactTriggerHelper.processSubCatRollUps(
    AccountSet,
    new Map<String, sObjectField> {
        'subCat1' => Account.Total_Sub1__c,
        'subCat2' => Account.Total_Consulting_LoS__c,
        'subCat3' => Account.Total_Sub2__c,
        'subCat4' => Account.Total_Sub3__c
    }
);
```

Some helpful notes:

- You can perform a DML on an empty list without errors or using governor limits.
- You don't need to query fields that you will never read the value from.
- AggregateResult queries are best for summarizing data in this manner.
- As a further exercise, you could query the accounts to be updated to see if they need to be updated to further optimize your DML.

Answer (score 0):

Overlooking the questionable coding standards, you can avoid triggering the Contact Trigger more than once on single transaction by following below :

If you don't already have an `after update` in your ContactTrigger, add it.
Then on the `ContactTriggerHandler.AfterUpdate` method

You can add this line of code :

> if(checkRecursive.firstcall){
> checkRecursive.firstcall = false; ContactTriggerHelper.processSubCatRollUps(AccountSet,'subCat1');
> ContactTriggerHelper.processSubCatRollUps(AccountSet,'subCat2');
> ContactTriggerHelper.processSubCatRollUps(AccountSet,'subCat3');
> ContactTriggerHelper.processSubCatRollUps(AccountSet,'subCat4');
> }

to make sure it only triggers once.